# iPhone: How to Embed NSData in XML for Upload to Server?

Tags: iphone, nsdata

I want to pass data to a server and store the file there in a database as binary data.

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathDoc]; 
pathDoc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<size>%d</size><type>%d</type><cdate>%@</cdate><file>%c</file><fname>File</fname>",fileSizeVal,filetype,creationDate,myData];
```

Any idea about this?

Thanks you,
Milan

Comment: What do you expect to print? CDATA section? Base-64 encoded data?

Comment: i want to pass data on server and store file on database as binary data
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathDoc]; 

pathDoc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<size>%d</size><type>%d</type><cdate>%@</cdate><file>%c</file><fname>File</fname>",fileSizeVal,filetype,creationDate,myData];

Answer (score 1):

This code makes no sense.

You create a NSData object with a path to a file then you turn around and reassign to the path var a string representing a chunk of XML. It's very muddled and likely to cause errors. Don't reuse variables this way.

In any case, to encode data to a string you use NSString's:

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Then just insert that string wherever you want it.

Edit:

> Hello, sorry for i dont know how to
>   use this - (id)initWithData:(NSData
>   *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding in
>   my code.

Like so: (Sorry about the formatting Stackoverflow's editor seems to be on blink today)

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathDoc]; 
NSString *myDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSString *formatString = @"<size>%d</size><type>%d</type><cdate>%@</cdate><file>%c</file><fname>File</fname><data>%@</data>";
pathDoc = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString,fileSizeVal,filetype,creationDate,myDataString];
```

The `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` is one of several constants defining a variety of string encodings. See the NSString class reference. Which one you use depends on what your server expects.

Good luck.

Comment: Hello,

sorry for i dont know how to use this - (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding in my code.

Thanks you,

Comment: See edit for detailed explanation. Don't forget to hit the checkmark next to the answer that best solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to embed binary data in an XML document is to encode the data to ASCII. For example using Base64.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use object archiving to create a serialized object and then send that to the server.

Comment: Hello,
i am frustrate 
can you send me the code so i will use 

Thakns you,